PDE-Laplace Question for actual equation
Solve
$u_{xx}+u_{yy}= 0$ in $(0,π) × (0,π),$
$u(0,y) = u(π,y) = 0$ for $y ∈ (0,π),$
$u(x,π) = 0$ for $x ∈ (0,π),$
$u(x,0) = 1$ for $x ∈ (0,π).$
What I have done so far:

I have tried asking Chegg and ChatGPT, but they provided me with different answers, making me more confused...

The steps you provided are not complete, but the form of the solution at the end is correct. The next step would be plugging in the boundary condition of $u(x,0)=1$ to solve for the Fourier coefficient $A_n$, which I believe is the major point that this problem is designed for.
BTW: please use $\LaTeX$ to typeset math equations MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

If I am getting your words correct, I should do $ A_n= \int_0^π (1*sin(nx) dx) $ next ?

There should be a $(1-e^{-2n\pi})$ factor somewhere with $A_n$.
